# Getting length of /proc/self/exe symlink

Tags: linux, symlink, stat

As mentioned on SO, readlink on /proc/self/exe can be used to get the executable path on linux. man 2 readlink recommends that one should use lstat to extract the required length of a path. However, when I stat /proc/self/exe, the st_size member is set to 0. How can I get the length for allocating the buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice, I would tend to use a reasonable size (e.g. 256 or 1024, or `PATH_MAX`) for `readlink` of `/proc/*/exe` (or `/proc/self/exe`)

The point is that almost always, executables are supposed to be started by humans, so either the `PATH` (for [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) or some shell) or the entire file path is human friendly. I don't know any people who explicitly uses very long filenames (not fitting in width in some terminal screen). I never heard of executable programs (or scripts) whose filename exceeds a hundred of bytes.

So just use a local buffer of some reasonable size (and perhaps `strdup` it on success if so needed). And [readlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) returns the number of meaningful bytes in its buffer (so if you really care, grow the buffer and make a loop till it fits).

For `readlink` of `/proc/self/exe`, I would do it into a 256 bytes buffer at initialization, and abort (with a meaningful error message) if it does not fit (or fail, e.g. because `/proc/` is not mounted).

Answer (score 1):

taken from `man 2 lstat`, under NOTES

> For most files under the /proc directory, stat() does  not  return 
>   the file  size in the st_size field; instead the field is returned
>   with the value 0.

That's why it does not work